# Comparing different strings in PHP with == returns true

Tags: php, string, comparison, string-comparison, comparison-operators

I was just debugging a script and found that an if-statement wasn't working the way I expected it to.

```
var_dump("6064365413078728979" == "6064365413078728452");
die();
```

The code above will result in the following:

```
bool(true)
```

With the === operator it works as expected. Anyone got any ideas why?

I'm using PHP Version 5.3.13 with a wamp installation on a x64 windows machine.

Comment: on my php version 5.3.10 your code returns false.

Comment: That returns false. Not sure how you're getting true.

Comment: it's because a non-empty string is equivalent to true.. you're like comparing TRUE == TRUE.. === operator however is sensitive with the data type

Comment: While we research, please could you say us what is the value of PHP_INT_MAX for your server?

Comment: int(2147483647) so you are right about that. Thx everybody for your help. Should i change the 'right' answer to yours for future purposes?

Comment: Oh, there is no need for that, Hanky is completing his answer. It's been a pleasure to help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
<?php
$a=6064365413078728979;
$b=6064365413078728452;
echo $a."<br>".$b;
//var_dump( $a==$b );
die();
?>
```

When you run that, then on your machine that might be exceeding limit for a number and that is a numeric comparison taking place. Try the script above and see value for $a will probably be different than the value you gave.

That is why when both are compared numerically they are equal. Hence use **===**  as suggested by others

Edit:  Explanation based upon @Axel's Advice.

[PHP Manual](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.float.php) explains

> The size of a float is platform-dependent, although a maximum of
>   ~1.8e308 with a precision of roughly 14 decimal digits is a common
>   value (the 64 bit IEEE format).

And [this website](http://www.herongyang.com/PHP/Data-Type-Overflow-of-Integer-and-Float-Values.html) is offering and explanation on the Overflow phenomenon and a small php code to test your system's integer and float range. Getting to know the limit on your servers will most probably explain it best why the offerflow occured

Comment: @Lubje See both are same :)

Comment: @HankyPanky, may you complete you answer with some link to PHPdocs about type juggling, [stirng conversion](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.conversion) and [PHP int and float limits](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.constants.php) to make a perfect wiki question of this? After doing so I'll delete my answer. If you feel happy to do that I'll be very glad.

Comment: Hmmm... Not exaclty. Our discovery was that in the end there was no overflow, but the strings were converted to float and the integer part was devaluated until both numbers were equal in its representation... Do you think you can improve ti?

Answer (score 7):

PHP has loose type comparison behavior, so your numerical strings are getting converted to integer types before `==` non strict comparison, and the conversion result is overflowing.

That is the principal reason to use `===` when it's possible.

Take a look at [this page](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.type-juggling.php) for further details on type juggling.

Comment: So they get converted, eventhough they are both strings?

Comment: Yes, maybe my aknowledges is a few limited, but PHP is the only language i've learnt that does this. But the answer is yes: PHP will see what's inside your strings befeore deciding how to cast them.

Comment: according to http://php.net/manual/en/types.comparisons.php `"0" == "1"` will give false, so this is not an explanation. Or rather, it is, but it could be improved to point out on the overflowing part.

Comment: @Gordon, in your case this is equal to `1 == 0`, but in this case integers are overflowing. Let me a second to add some information about PHP integer limits (which depends on the machine, so there will be some interesting info in that)

Comment: Hmmm... interesting... [this](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.conversion) says that if the number exceedes PHP_INT_MAX it will be converted to float, so now we have to find out why float comparison is giving us true. Please don't upvote my answer until someone finds out what's happening.

Comment: @Áxel  Its not just about int. Even floats have a limit based upon architecture. So your answer still stands true. In his case this limit might be exceding.

Comment: @HankyPanky float limits being exceeded by 6064365413078728979?? I don't believe so. Good point anyway.

Comment: @Áxel the float value for both numeric strings is 6.0643654130787E+18 as pointed out in the comment below Hanky's answer.

Comment: Yes, it can exceed based on architecture. Although i do not know exact max right now but he could be on a 32 bit architecture and that limits out below that point probably

Comment: @HankyPanky I have just seen it, we were loosing the other part of the conversation hahaha. I'll delete my answer to avoid a more clear question result.

Comment: @Áxel No No please dont delete it, it offers a good explanation and discussion

Comment: @HankyPanky ahha, because yours has been chosen as correct, future visitors will look just at yours, so I encourage you to edit it to explain the issue the best as possible, and this way we're building a good wiki. This is Stackoverflow ;)